# Use .loc by default for Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know the common methods to accesss index / columns in a Pandas dataframe (see also indexing [guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)):

- `df.iloc[..., ...]` for integer location
- `df.loc[..., ...]` for label-based location
- `df.ix` (deprecated)
- `df['C1']` or `df.C1` for column access
- `df['mylabel1':'mylabel10']` or `df[2:7]` for row slice access, but `df['mylabel1']` and `df[2]` obviously don't work

I have always found the *two last* bullet points confusing, since we use the same notation `df[...]` for both column access or row access.

**Question: is there a way to configure Pandas (or a subclass of `DataFrame`) that simplifies everything such that:**

```
df[...] is in fact an alias for df.loc[...]
```

**?**

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame(columns=['C1', 'C1', 'C2'])
x.loc['a'] = [np.random.rand(2000, 500), np.random.rand(2000, 500), np.random.rand(2000)]
print(x.loc['a', 'C2'])
x['a', 'C2']       # should give the same thing, so that by default, x[...] is the same as x.loc[...]
```

Comment: I think it's best to just write .loc. If you would have a configuration like that, your code is suddenly not portable to other environments without the same configuration. Best to learn to speak and write the same dialect of pandas as everyone else, you could say.  (Configuration is not composable, you suddenly can't call other's pandas code and have it work correctly.)

Comment: @creanion. Yes that's true. But on the other hand, there could be a subclass of `DataFrame` that would just do that. It would be so convenient. The `df['column']` and `df['row1:row10']` confusing-syntax is really something that would be great to avoid :)

Comment: I think you mean `df[row1:row10]`. I'll be honest, I use pandas a lot and I didn't even know about that one, so it hasn't burdened me. I use `.loc[]`, `.iloc[]` and `df[`<column(s)>`]`

Comment: @creanion You're right, I meant `df['rowlabel1':'rowlabel2']` or `df[2:113]` slices.

Comment: You can of course write `xl=x.loc`; is that good enough?

Comment: @DavisHerring This could be a solution indeed, you can post it as an answer. It would be great for future Pandas versions that the "default" indexing of `df` is `df.iloc`. (It might avoid the strangeness of bullet points #4 and #5 in my question)

Answer (score 2):

Every **expression** in Python has an object as a result, so you can assign it to a name:

```
xl=x.loc
xl['a']=…           # equivalent to x.loc['a']=…
```

You can't emulate `x.loc=…` this way, since assigning to `xl` will simply **rebind** the name; that's probably irrelevant here, but for completeness the only way to (slightly) shorten such things is to write something like

```
class Setter:
  def __init__(self,x): self.x=x
  def __getattr__(self,n):
    return lambda(v): setattr(self.x,n,v)
xset=Setter(x).loc
xset(…)             # equivalent to x.loc=…
```

If you want to have one name that still supports **other** access modes, you can write a wrapper class:

```
class DFLoc:
  def __init__(self,x): self.x=x
  def __getitem__(self,k): return self.x.loc[k]
  def __getattr__(self,n): return getattr(self.x,n)
```

This approach also allows you to support libraries that rely on the fact that a constructed result from something like `x.loc` is used only **once** with `__setitem__` afterwards.  (This would generally be a bug in such libraries, although in some cases the *value* of such a computed attribute would depend on the changes made through it.)

Comment: Thanks! It's rarely necessary to set `df.loc = … ` (I never had to do this), so probably just doing `dfl = df.loc` and then `dfl['a'] = ...`, as you suggested will be enough :)

Comment: It would be great for future Pandas versions that the *default* indexing for DataFrame is `loc`, i.e. `df[something]` in the future would be equivalent to `df.loc[something]`, this would require to redefine getitem etc. Since `df.ix` is deprecated and the fact the bullet points #4 and #5 in my question lead to strange things, having `df.loc` as default indexer would really make sense for future versions of Pandas :) Only drawback: compatibility with previous code :)